# Handlebars dynamic property lookup in each loop

Tags: handlebars.js

In Handlebars 2+, how do I dynamically read a property in a loop like this? `objects` is an array of objects. `keys` is an array of strings. I want to loop each key for each object and put the its `.foo` value in the `span`.

```
{{#each objects}}
    {{#each keys}}
        <span>{{../this.{{this}}.foo}}</span>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Is this possible in plain Handlebars 2+? Or...is there a [helper](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers) that does this?

Answer (score 8):

I don't see the way how it can be done without helper.
With helpers everything is possible (but kind of ugly) in Handlebars.

For example, you could use something like this:

```
{{#each objects}}
    {{#each keys}}
        <span>{{lookupProp ../this this 'foo'}}</span>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

And helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('lookupProp', function (obj, key, prop) {
   return obj[key] && obj[key][prop];
});
```

Look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpre0wc3/1/).

Handlebars has built-in `lookup` [helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) since version 3.0.3.

Answer (score 7):

Okay... spent a few hours googling around and find a nice solution, as I had the same issue, but failed to find any...

I was as happy as Larry and jumped off my chair when I finally figured a way to get this working :D

This way, you can **access object values with dynamic keys**,

Demo object:

```
var categories = {
    onion: { name: 'bar', id: 4 }, 
    apple: { name: 'demo', id: 2 }, 
    carrot: { name: 'foo', id: 3 }, 
    Root: [
        { name: 'apple' },
        { name: 'onion' },
        { name: 'carrot' }
    ]
};
```

Instead of trying something like these: (which won't work)

```
{{#each categories.[@key]}} 
or
{{#each categories.[mykey]}}
```

You can do:

```
{{#each categories.[Root] as |main-category|}}

    {{#each (lookup ../categories main-category.name) as |sub-category|}}

        {{sub-category.name}}

    {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

Hope it will help for someone else too :)

Comment: That worked for me! In short, if you want to iterate over `object[key]`, you can use `{{#each (lookup object key)}}`

Comment: I tried and got struck on using object[key] but you made my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else that doesn't want to loop you could use `with` eg.

```
{{#with (lookup myObject myKeyVar) as |subObject|}}
  {{subObject.key}}
{{/with}}
```